# pg-promise using named parameters on an update results in ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js, pg-promise

I feel like I'm missing something very simple here.

I'm attempting to use named parameters with `pg-promise` as [outlined here.](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters)

I'm using this nested in a `db.task` function, `editProductObj` is obtained from an HTML form on my website. A MWE would be as follows:

```
db.task('edit-product', async t => {

    console.log(editProductObj)

    console.log(typeof(editProductObj))

    console.log('display' in editProductObj)

    // update product
    await t.none(`UPDATE
                      product
                  SET
                      display = ${display},
                      product_date = ${product_date}
                  WHERE
                      product_id = ${product_id}`, editProductObj)

}).catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
```

Which outputs this to console:

```
{
   display: 'true',
   product_date: 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
   product_id: '1'
} // object looks like what I expected
object // object is indeed an object
true // display is in the object passed
```

and also outputs the error:

```
ReferenceError: display is not defined
```

This makes me believe that the `t.none` function isn't accessing the `editProductObj` object properly as the `console.log` output suggests the input is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ES6 template strings, and not [Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters) of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

As documented, the library supports flexible syntax with its [Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters):

> syntax $*propName*, with * being any of the following open-close pairs: {}, (), <>, [], //

And if you want to use [Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters) from inside an ES6 template string, you need to use one of the library's alternative open-close-pairs, to avoid the syntax conflict:

- `$(propName)`
- `$[propName]`
- `$<propName>`
- `$/propName/`

You can only use syntax `${propName}` from inside regular strings or external SQL files.

**Examples**

This one will work correctly:

```
await t.none(`UPDATE
                      product
                  SET
                      display = $/display/,
                      product_date = $/product_date/
                  WHERE
                      product_id = $/product_id/`, editProductObj)
```

And so will this one:

```
await t.none('UPDATE product SET display = ${display}, ' +
             'product_date = ${product_date} WHERE ' +
             'product_id = ${product_id}', editProductObj)
```

If you want to properly manage complex SQL, you should use it externally, via [Query Files](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-files), and you will be able to use the `${propName}` syntax there ;)

Comment: Query files, interesting, I seem to learn something new about pg-promise everyday.

Comment: @BML91 [Query Files](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-files) are one of the most powerful features of the library. See [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo), or how some of the large projects are using it, like [LISK](https://github.com/LiskHQ/lisk/tree/development/db).

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing javascript string templates with pg-promise templates. Just change your back-ticks to single quotes.

Comment: I thought it would be simple. Interesting, I'm getting a new error now, but probably outside the scope of this question. Thanks.